# Obtain Java hour from String of type "hh:mm:ss"

Tags: java, string

I have two Strings of the format "hh:mm:ss".I want to obtain only the hour part of both strings and find the difference between them.How should i do it.I tried Dateformat and parse function but when i subtract, it tells bad operand types. 
Code:

```
 String ta="";
 String tb="";
 int diff;
 Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
 ta=s.nextLine();
 tb=s.nextLine();
 DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh");
 Date date1 = sdf.parse(ta);
 Date date2 = sdf.parse(tb);
 diff=sdf.format(date1)-sdf.format(date2);
 if(diff==20)
     System.out.println("Twenty");
```

Comment: If you want help fixing your code, you need to [edit] your question to include the code that's giving the error so we can see what you did.  Describing your code ("I tried Dateformat") isn't helpful.

Comment: You should search for an answer before posting a question... Please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Comment: Is the input a duration (that implies possible hour values greater than 24) or a clock time?

Comment: No,the strings will vary between "24:59:59" to "00:00:00"

Comment: Well, if "24:59:59" is allowed then this excludes any answers based on either `SimpleDateFormat` or `java.time.DateTimeFormatter`. You need a duration parser, either home-made like in the answer of @rememberthetitans (but better with extra hour adjustment as sketched in my comment below) or via a 3rd-party library. Standard Java has no duration parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need to convert it to `Date` at all:

```
String time1 = "07:00:55";
String time2 = "05:00:33";
String time1Sub = time1.substring(0, time1.indexOf(':'));
String time2Sub = time2.substring(0, time2.indexOf(':'));
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(time1Sub) - Integer.parseInt(time2Sub));
```

**Edit:**

As per comment below, if you want *full* hours, you can check the difference in the hour slots (feel free to edit if there are better ways to do this).

```
String hour1 = time1.substring(time1.lastIndexOf(':') - 2, time1.lastIndexOf(':'));
String hour2 = time2.substring(time1.lastIndexOf(':') - 2, time2.lastIndexOf(':'));
int result = Integer.parseInt(time1Sub) - Integer.parseInt(time2Sub);
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(hour1) < Integer.parseInt(hour2) ? result - 1 : result);
```

Comment: I'm. Not sure why this is down voted. It seems reasonable.

Comment: Yes, it is simple and straightforward and even better than the suggested alternative to let `LocalTime` parse the input because this answer is capable to process hour values >= 24 (for the case, the input is meant as duration and not clock time). However, the hour delta should probably be reduced by one for the case if the subhour-part of first input is bigger than the subhour-part of second input to be compared.

Comment: @MenoHochschild added optional edit for *full* hours.

Answer (score 0):

Using java.time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.time.LocalTime a = java.time.LocalTime.parse("12:00:00");
    System.out.println(a.getHour());

}
```

Comment: The OP says: Input like "24:59:59" might be expected so your answer would not work in this case.